Does Liquibase mongodb extension support versions 7.X and 8.X?
According to the documentation, the extension supports only MongoDB 5.X and 6.X:
https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/database-tutorials/mongodb/
This lack seems weird to me, did anyone try the extension with MongoDB 8 ?
